# Delete with subselect without WHERE or IN (Key-Preserved-Table)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Here is a delete clause, it's work perfectly for me, but i'm wondering how does the oracle know which table to delete the data?

```
delete from (select * from t1 join t2  
on t1.field1 = t2.field1)
```

What is the mechanism to determine which table will be deleted?

In my case the data was deleted from t1, the relation between t1 and t2 is n -> 1.

If I change the order of the subselect return, the result will be the same:

```
delete from (select * from t2 join t1  
on t1.field1 = t2.field1)
```

Comment: @Piyush question is why the data is deleted from `t1` table why not `t2`

Comment: As NoDisplayName said, my question is why the data is deleted from t1, since the result of subselect is a join of two tables, if I had put 

`delete from (select t1.* from t1 join t2  
on t1.field1 = t2.field1)` 

it will be completely normal delete from t1, but I put  `select *`

Comment: "how does the oracle know"? That is why it's called Oracle ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle will only delete from the so called [key preserved table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006318). That is the table whose key is preserved in the resulting join. In other words, the rows of the key preserved table can only appear *once* in the result join.

Here, because of the foreign key constraint, you have a `n -> 1` mapping between t1 and t2. So Oracle will necessarily choose `t1` as the key preserving table as you might have potentially several times the same rows of `t2` in the join result.

---

The key-preserving property of a table does not depend on the actual data in the table. It is a property of its schema. Per OP request in a comment below, here is an example:

```
create table a (n int primary key);
create table b (n int);

insert into a values(1);
insert into b values(1);
insert into b values(1);
```

The following statement will delete rows from `b` :

```
delete from (select * from a join b on a.n = b.n);
```

Why rows from b ? Because, Oracle can ensure there is a one-to-one mapping between rows in table `b` and row in the result set. So, `b` is the *key preserved table*. See:

```
select a.*, a.rowid, b.*, b.rowid from a join b on a.n = b.n;

  a.n | a.ROWID            | b.n| b.ROWID
  ----+--------------------+----+-------------------
    1 | AAAKUKAAEAAAAv8AAA |  1 | AAAKUMAAEAAAAwMAAA 
    1 | AAAKUKAAEAAAAv8AAA |  1 | AAAKUMAAEAAAAwMAAB
```

Comment: If I have two tables is a join, but one has no PK, the Oracle will choose that table to be key preserved? I have tested, and there was no value whose appears only once in join, but the oracle deleted the data of table whose there was no PK, but if the two tables had PK, the oracle will got an error, saying that is necessary to have a key preserved table.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you an example why Oracle will delete rows from the "non PK" table in your first use case. Please note however the key preserved table is *not* a property of the data, but a property of the schema. So Oracle will behave the same even if there is no duplicate *values* in the `b` table. As about your second use case, I don't know exactly how you conducted your test, but very probably Oracle had either *no* or *two* possible key preserved table -- and complains that it don't know from which one you want to delete rows (Oracle will delete row of *one* table only)

Comment: All that being said, I wouldn't recommend you to use that `DELETE FROM (SELECT ... JOIN  ...)` syntax as it is too much confusing to say the least. You generally can (and _should_ ?) rewrite that as `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ... IN (SELECT ... )`. Check the query execution plan, but it should be (nearly) the same.

Comment: first thank you for the explanations, more one doubt:
if you remove the PK from the first table Oracle will get an error like "cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table" , why can't deleted even there is no duplicate row? If the two tables have PK, then the operation goes normal (deleting the non duplicate data). I understand that is a property of schema, but the error when has no PK is stranger.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller Don't think in terms of "duplicate rows". Think in terms of "invariant" provided by the schema. Without any PK, uniqueness in *not guaranteed* and Oracle cannot assume a 1-to-1 mapping between any table and the join result set.